# Using variables in awk statement

Tags: awk, configuration

I have a file that I am performing some replacement of certain columns in two new files. It works fine right now.

I wanted to put some of the variables like the "X" (the character I replace a column with) and "\036" separator, the columns selected like $13, $6,$10,$5, etc into a configuration file kind of like below. I am not sure how to accomplish this the best way with an awk statement.

Config:

```
export FIELD_DELIMITER="\036"
export MASK_COLUMN="$13"
export PRINT_COLUMN="$13, $6, $10, $5"
```

Code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\036"} {gsub(/./, "X", $13)} 1' $1 > $file_directory'/'$mask_filename$seperation$temp$DATA_SUFFIX
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\036"} {print$6,$10,$5,$13}' $1 > $file_directory'/'$mask_filename$seperation$temp1$DATA_SUFFIX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `awk` variables from outside by using the `-v` argument. You can use it repeatedly to pass multiple variables.

For example, for the first line of your script:

```
awk -v FIELD_DELIMITER='\036' -v WIPEOUT_CHARACTER='X' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=FIELD_DELIMITER} {gsub(/./, WIPEOUT_CHARACTER, $13)} 1' $1 > $file_directory'/'$mask_filename$seperation$temp$DATA_SUFFIX
```

I checked GNU Awk 4.1.4 and it's happy to take the "\036" and interpret that as ASCII RS (record separator), so I'd expect that should work for you too.